# Commutativity and polar factorization of a normal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Suppose the polar factorization of $X = YZ$.

Since $X$ is non-singular we can re-write $X = (UV^T)(V\Sigma V^T)$.

Now, question is can you prove that $YZ = ZY$ if $X$ is normal? In other words, can you prove:

$$ (UV^T)(V\Sigma V^T)=(V\Sigma V^T)(UV^T) $$

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, sorry English is not my native language

Comment: Note that $X^TX = Z^2$, and $XX^T = Y^TZ^2Y$

Comment: Would you please elaborate how that would transform into $YZ = ZY$? @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, verify that $X^TX = Z^2$ and $XX^T = Y^TZ^2Y$.  If $X$ is normal, then we have
$$
Z^2 = Y^TZ^2Y \implies 
YZ^2 = Z^2Y
$$
Now, note that $Z$ is the unique positive semidefinite square root of $Z^2$. By taking a close look at the theorem guaranteeing positive semidefinite square roots, note that
$$
YZ^2 = Z^2Y \implies YZ = ZY
$$
which is the desired conclusion.  More specifically, it suffices to note that there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $Z = p(Z^2)$.

Comment: Since $YZ^2 = Z^2Y$, and $Z$ has a unique square root, then why must $YZ = ZY$?